# using dictionary to get mapped values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a situation wherein there are substitutions for items possible. Say:

```
mapping = {904:905, 905:906}
```

There is a dataframe wherein I have quantities for each of the item described above. If the dataframe is as below:

```
904 0kg
905 10kg
906 15kg
```

when `904` is `0`, I want the function to get the mapped value of `904` which is `905` (10kg)

if `905` is also having `0kg`, then the function should get `906` (`15kg`)

so far i have tried as below

```
mapping={904:905,905:906}
map=mapping[904]
on_hand_qty = oh_df['ON_HAND'][oh_df['WH_ITEM_CODE']==904].values
print(on_hand_qty)
if on_hand_qty==0:
    on_hand_qty=oh_df['ON_HAND'][oh_df['WH_ITEM_CODE']==map].values
print(on_hand_qty)
```

I want this if condition to perform as long as on_hand_qty does not equal to zero

Comment: alright, can you show us your code what you have so far?

Comment: What is your question and what are you trying to do? Why is 904 0kg? Is that also in a dict? At what part is 904 0? Is that also in yet another dict? Does 0 mean 0kg or yet something else? Most importantly, what have you tried so far and what specific problem did you encounter and need help with?

Comment: 904 0kg is a situation, If the item 904 is having a non zero value, i need not run the code. When the item is having 0 kg value, I want to use the mapping and get the value from the mapped item. in this case I would get the mapping of 904 which is 905 and the value should get updated to 10 kg.

Comment: Are you looking for a ``while`` loop, perhaps?

Comment: can `while` loop solve the purpose? I will give it a try. thanks for that guess

Answer (score 0):

```
while on_hand_qty==0:
    on_hand_qty=oh_df['ON_HAND'][oh_df['WH_ITEM_CODE']==x].values
    print(on_hand_qty)
    if on_hand_qty>0:
        break
    else:
        x=mapping[x]
```

This resolved it.